# Can I get a reference to a calling class in a static method?

Tags: java

I have a static Java method, where I want to know who is its caller. Is it possible to get this information in Java?

Comment: search around, there are multiple questions. The key is to get the stack trace, but it is not advisable to do so

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's *possible*, but it's expensive and in anything remotely like a normal case, it's a very bad idea. You almost certainly want to approach the problem you're solving in another way. *(And if you post a new question about the problem you're solving, I bet someone will help you do that! :-) )*

Two ways you can generate a stack trace:

#### 1) Via `Throwable`

...by throwing and catching an exception, and then using [`Exception#getStackTrace`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#getStackTrace())

```
try {
    throw new Exception();
}
catch (Exception e) {
    // Get the stack trace
    StackTraceElement[] entries = e.getStackTrace();
}
```

...or as [lscoughlin points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4152317/can-i-get-a-reference-to-a-calling-class-in-a-static-method/4153108#4153108) (please vote him/her up), **rather more directly** through simply `new Throwable`:

```
StackTraceElement[] entries = new Throwable().getStackTrace();
```

Each of those [`StackTraceElement`s](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StackTraceElement.html) then gives you information about that point in the stack trace. In your case, you'd probably want to look at `StackTraceElement`'s [`getClassName`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StackTraceElement.html#getClassName()) method. If you really need a reference to the calling class *object*, you can pass that class name string into [`Class.forName`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName(java.lang.String)) but be warned that in complex environments, you might get a different instance (or no instance) of the class if the caller has done interesting things with class loaders.

#### 2) By using [`Thread#getStackTrace`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#getStackTrace())

MRalwasser helpfully points out below that in Java 5 or higher (and I'm guessing you're probably using Java 5 or higher), you can use `Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()` instead of actually throwing an exception. I don't know whether it would be lighterweight or not (as getting the stack trace may well be what's expensive about throwing an exception), but it's definitely cleaner.

In a [quick and dirty test](http://pastie.org/1289664), counter-intuitively actually throwing the exception seemed faster than going via `Thread` (and was pretty much the same as `new Throwable`), but the vagaries of naive profiling of JVM applications are well documented, your mileage may vary...

But again, not only is getting a stack trace an expensive process, but using information about the caller that the caller hasn't passed you via the method signature is a serious design issue in anything other than (say) a debugger or error tracer used only for development. The main answer here has to be: Don't do that, unless you have a really good reason to.

Comment: +1 for the *bad idea*. Though it might be temporarily useful for debugging purposes.

Comment: @mklhmmm: Exactly, I've totally used it for debugging when the situation was hard to walk through with a debugger.

Comment: If Java 5 or above is being used, you should use Thread.getCurrentThread().getStackTrace() instead. Although it's the same idea, it should be little bit more lightweight.

Comment: @TJ I think that you should edit your answer and place `Thread.getCurrentThread().getStackTrace()` on top of it.

Comment: @Vincenzo: I think I'll leave it, but I'll make it clearer. In the meantime, I've corrected it -- it's `Thread.currentThread` rather than `Thread.getCurrentThread`. Ah, the joys of an inconsistent API... ;-)

Comment: why is this a bad idea?

Comment: @brown.2179: Because if the method needs to know its caller, it's using external information. Instead, it should accept an argument that tells it what it needs to know. Amongst other things, that makes the method testable.

Answer (score 8):

Sorry to resurrect this thread but the mechanism I've been using for ages to accomplish this same thing without the cumbersome use of stacktraces.

---

```
class ClassloaderUtil {

    public static Class getCallingClass() {
        return CallerResolver.getCallerClass(2);
    }

    private static final class CallerResolver extends SecurityManager {
        private static final CallerResolver CALLER_RESOLVER = new CallerResolver();
        private static final int CALL_CONTEXT_OFFSET = 3; // may need to change if this class is redesigned
        protected Class[] getClassContext() {
            return super.getClassContext();
        }

        /*
        * Indexes into the current method call context with a given
        * offset.
        */
        private static Class getCallerClass(int callerOffset) {
            return CALLER_RESOLVER.getClassContext()[CALL_CONTEXT_OFFSET + callerOffset];
        }
        private static int getContextSize() {
            return CALLER_RESOLVER.getClassContext().length - CALL_CONTEXT_OFFSET;
        }
    }

}
```

Then using it is as simple as this:

```
public class ClassloaderUtilTest {

    @Test
    public void test() {
        Class c = ClassloaderUtil.getCallingClass();
        Assert.assertNotNull(c);
        c = foo();
        Assert.assertNotNull(c);
    }

    private Class foo() {
        return ClassloaderUtil.getCallingClass();
    }
}
```

The first class will be some junit framework class whereas foo() will return ClassloaderUtilTest as the class.

It is definitely not perfect. However, it does have its random uses. I agree with the folks that have already answered this question in that this is incredibly expensive.

Comment: How expensive is this?

Answer (score 7):

It's easier and slightly safer to just new a thowable, as in:

```
   Throwable t = new Throwable();
   StackTraceElement directCaller = t.getStackTrace()[1];
```

But Generally speaking -- it's still a terrible idea, and it is expensive.

**UPDATE**:
Since java9 you you have the StackWalker - so I use a thing that looks like this now.

```
import java.lang.StackWalker.StackFrame;

public class Backtrace {


    private static final StackWalker stackWalker = StackWalker.getInstance(StackWalker.Option.SHOW_HIDDEN_FRAMES);


    public static StackFrame backTrace() {
        var stackFrame = stackWalker.walk((stream -> stream
                .limit(2)
                .reduce((one, two) -> two)));
        return stackFrame.orElseThrow();
    }

    public static StackFrame backTrace(int framesBack) {
        var stackFrame = stackWalker.walk((stream -> stream
                .limit(2 + framesBack)
                .reduce((one, two) -> two)));

        return stackFrame.orElseThrow();
    }
}
```

Comment: `new Throwable` Doh!! And to make things worse, this is not even the first time I've made that mistake... Big +1.

Comment: Ha!  @T.J.Crowder Thanks for the kudos :P

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this solution using ASM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4024587/get-callers-method-not-name/4024969#4024969) for [a similar previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4024587/get-callers-method-not-name/). Unfortunately [my own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4024587/get-callers-method-not-name/4024849#4024849) was not quite that good. But I agree with the *bad idea* part.