# See java annotations on calling method

Tags: java, reflection, annotations

Let's say I have a situation like this:

```
public String method(String s) {
    return stringForThisVisibility(s, EnumVisibility.PUBLIC);
}
```

and I want to replace it with an annotation like this:

```
@VisibilityLevel(value = EnumVisibility.PUBLIC)
public String method(String s) {
    return stringForThisVisibility(s);
}
```

This seems to be a better and more clear solution, but i need for stringForThisVisibility method to know value of @VisibilityLevel with some kind of reflection. Is that possible? Can I see the annotations on the method calling stringForThisVisibility?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to obtain the [`Method`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html) object that represents the method that called  `stringForThisVisibility`. Unfortunately, Java doesn't offer this functionality out of the box.

However, we can still obtain the `Method` via the information returned by [`Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#getStackTrace%28%29). That method returns an array of [`StackTraceElement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StackTraceElement.html) objects. Each `StackTraceElement` object tells us three things:

- The *name* of the class ([`getClassName()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StackTraceElement.html#getClassName%28%29))
- The *name* of the method ([`getMethodName()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StackTraceElement.html#getMethodName%28%29))
- The line number ([`getLineNumber()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StackTraceElement.html#getLineNumber%28%29))

It may take some experimentation, but you should find which index in that array represents the method you're interested in (it will probably be the first, second or third `StackTraceElement` in the array).

Once you have the desired `StackTraceElement`, you can obtain its corresponding `Method` object using the technique in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4024969/41619) to the question entitled ["Get caller's method (java.lang.reflect.Method)"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4024587/41619). That technique will still word, even if the class has more than one method with that method name. There are simpler techniques if you're not worried about that scenario.

Once you have the `Method` object, it's just a matter of calling [`method.getAnnotation(VisibilityLevel.class)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#getAnnotation%28java.lang.Class%29).

Answer (score 10):

With the following class:

```
 /**
   * Proper use of this class is
   *     String testName = (new Util.MethodNameHelper(){}).getName();
   *  or
   *     Method me = (new Util.MethodNameHelper(){}).getMethod();
   * the anonymous class allows easy access to the method name of the enclosing scope.
   */
  public static class MethodNameHelper {
    public String getName() {
      final Method myMethod = this.getClass().getEnclosingMethod();
      if (null == myMethod) {
        // This happens when we are non-anonymously instantiated
        return this.getClass().getSimpleName() + ".unknown()"; // return a less useful string
      }
      final String className = myMethod.getDeclaringClass().getSimpleName();
      return className + "." + myMethod.getName() + "()";
    }

    public Method getMethod() {
      return this.getClass().getEnclosingMethod();
    }
  }
```

One can call:
       Method me = (new Util.MethodNameHelper(){}).getMethod();

I make extensive use of the getName() call in that class. On my machine those anonymous class instantiations plus method invocations tend to cost about 1500 ns each. The StackElement walking approach costs about 30 times as much (47000 ns) on my machine in my performance test.

Answer (score 7):

yes you could.
something along the lines of

```
StackTraceElement[] stack = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
Class callerClass = Class.forName(stack[stack.length-2].getClassName());
callerClass.isAnnotationPresent(...)
```

the code above looks for annotations on the class. you could combine class name and method name (also from the stack trace element) and go look at the method. do note that this is extremely slow.

Comment: Thats the only solution I know, too. Not that it is not guaranteed to work in all situations: If the classloader which loaded the called class does not know the calling class (and none of its parent classloaders does), the call to `Class.forName()` will fail.

Comment: this technique is fragile (what if your method wasnt called directly from an annotated method? you'd need to loop through the stack. what if the annotation is on a superclass method and not on the calling method directly? you'd need to loop over superclasses...) and if Philipp is right it might screw up for complex environments (j2ee? osgi?). its also very slow.
you could opt for a solution that uses a ThreadLocal marker and set the marker before calling the method, but that would also look weird. maybe if you could describe what exactly youre trying to do an elegant solution could be found